# Iterated conditional expectations on Markov chains

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

De Cooman, Hermans, and Quaeghebeur's ["Imprecise Markov Chains and their Limit Behaviour"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/probability-in-the-engineering-and-informational-sciences/article/imprecise-markov-chains-and-their-limit-behavior/DF646257C294C16C2733F7C563F73730#) (also [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0980)) equation (4) defines the operator

$$\mathbb{T}_n f(x_{1:n}) := E(f(x_{1:n},\cdot)|x_n) = \sum_{x_{n+1} \in \cal X}f(x_{1:n},x_{n+1})p(x_{n+1}|x_n)$$

where $x_{1:n}$ is an abbreviation for $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$, values of a Markov chain with state space $\cal X$ at subsequent times, and $f(x_{1:n},\cdot)$ is $f(x_{1:n+1})$ as a function of $x_{n+1}$ with $x_{1:n}$ treated as fixed.  (I modified the notation very slightly to avoid unnecessary explanation here.)

Equation (5), which I understand and probably don't need to reproduce here, shows that $E(f|x_{1:N-1}) = \mathbb{T}_{N-1}f(x_{1:N-1})$.  I'm confused by equation (6):

$$E(f|x_{1:N-2}) = E(E(f(x_{1:N-2},\cdot,\cdot)|x_{1:N-2}, \cdot)\,|\,x_{1:N-2})
= \mathbb{T}_{N-2}\mathbb{T}_{N-1}f(x_{1:N-2})$$

The rhs should be read as $(\mathbb{T}_{N-2}(\mathbb{T}_{N-1}f))(x_{1:N-2})$.  I understand the first equation but not the second in (6).

---

EDIT: On the advice of folks in Meta, I've deleted the rest of the original post, as well as early revisions of it that I made in response to equaeghe's helpful comments.  I was unable to clarify the question sufficiently the first time around, but I have a new understanding, so I'll try a different approach now that I've thought about it further.

---

I want to make all arguments and scope relations explicit, so I'll use the $\lambda$ operator from lambda calculus to indicate function arguments.  [For example, to treat $f(x,y)$ as a function of $y$, one could write $(\lambda y)f(x,y)$.]  I'll also use subscripts on the expectation operator $E$ to clarify what variable the expectation is over.  (In the article, subscripts on $E$ have a different meaning.)

Let $n$ above be $N-1$ as in the article, and define

$$g := \mathbb{T}_{N-1}\,f = (\lambda x_{1:N-1})\,E_{x_N}(f(x_{1:N-1},x_N)|x_{N-1}).$$

This rhs is simply the definition of $\mathbb{T}_n$ with $N-1$ substituted for $n$, and abstractions made explicit.  This will make the notation dense, but I have trouble seeing what I'm doing without it.

I'll start from the far right hand side of equation (6) without the argument $x_{1:N-2}$ and then expand $\mathbb{T}_{N-2}(\mathbb{T}_{N-1}f)$ using the notation I described a moment ago:

$$\mathbb{T}_{N-2}\,g =$$
$$(\lambda x_{1:N-2})\,E_{x_{N-1}}[g(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}] =$$
$$(\lambda x_{1:N-2})\,E_{x_{N-1}}[(\mathbb{T}_{N-1}\,f)(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}] =$$
$$(\lambda x_{1:N-2})\,E_{x_{N-1}}[[(\lambda x_{1:N-1})E_{x_N}(f(x_{1:N-1},x_N)](x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1})|x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}]$$

Now substitute the argument $(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1})$ for the parameters specified by $\lambda$ inside the inner expectation:

$$= (\lambda x_{1:N-2})\,E_{x_{N-1}}[E_{x_N}(f(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1},x_N)|x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}]$$

If we then pass $x_{1:N-2}$ to this function (since that's what the rhs of (6) said) and remove the subscripts on the expectation operators, we get:

$$E[E(f(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1},x_N)|x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}]$$

This is similar to the middle of equation (6).  The conditioned function $f$ with its arguments is the same. (See equaghe's comment on the meaning of the dots in (6).)  The conditioning variables are different, however:  Where I have $x_{N-2}$, equation (6) has $x_{1:N-2}$, and where I have $x_{N-1}$, (6) has $x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1}$.

What have I done wrong?  (Answer or not, thanks to anyone who wades through this notation.)

Comment: Two remarks that may be useful to integrate first in your question: (i) The final argument of Eq. (6) is $x_{1:N-2}$. (ii) The RHS should be read as $(\mathbb{T}_{N-2}(\mathbb{T}_{N-1}f))(x_{1:N-2})$ as per the definition of $\mathbb{T}_n$.

Comment: Thanks @equaeghe.  I fixed the typo, but want to think about that interpretation of $\mathbb{T}_n$ before proceeding.  Maybe that's the source of my misunderstanding.  I knew that the other operator T$_n$ was to be interpreted as applying directly to $f$, but I had misinterpreted the definition of $\mathbb{T}_n$.

Comment: The middle part of (6) may be rewritten, using random variable notation, as $E(E(f(x_{1:N-2},X_{N-1},X_N)|x_{1:N-2}, X_{N-1})\,|\,x_{1:N-2})$. Also, it may be useful to let $g:=\mathbb{T}_{N-1}f$. (In case you find the answer to your original question, I think it would be most useful if you add it below; your exact confusion is not yet clear to me, and I'm lazy as well.)

Comment: Thanks @equaeghe.  That's very helpful.  You have provided quite a bit of help already, and you have no responsibility to provide support in the first place (nor to be a mind-reader).  I'm working on a revision of the question (or maybe the answer) based on your suggestions.  Also, in the end this is a just a question about some Markov chain equations, so I may get help from others as well.

Comment: And, closing yourself your question while you work on it is not an option because? Five months now...

Comment: I didn't know about that, @Did.  I can close it myself and then reopen it?  Sounds like a good solution.  How do I do that?  When I click on *close*, it just offers to let me vote along with others (which surprises me a little because I don't have close vote power on Math.SE.) (What reason would I give?  Yeah, it's unclear, but that's because it's not done.)  As for the five months, yes, it remained open and no one answered.  Then I did some additional thinking in the last week or so and finally saw that it could be clarified.   I was advised on Meta to revise rather than delete and ask anew.

Comment: Choose *delete*.

Comment: In the very first equation,$$E(f(x_{1:n},\cdot)|x_n) = \sum_{x_{n+1} \in \cal X}f(x_{1:n},x_{n+1})p(x_{n+1}|x_n)$$ is trivially wrong since the LHS depends on $x_n$ while the RHS depends on $x_{1:n}$.

Comment: @Did thanks for the clarification about close/delete and for pointing out a possible error.  I'm not sure what you're saying is wrong with the first equation.  It's copied directly from the published article with trivial modifications.  A similar equation occurs in a [book chapter (11)](http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470973811.html) on the same subject by one of the same authors.  (Maybe I didn't explain the the $x_{1:n}$ abbreviation clearly?)

Comment: @Did, I don't think my question should be deleted or closed now, but if you think that I should have deleted the question before the current round of revisions, I was thinking the same thing.  The only advice I got was a comment [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27327/i-was-confused-when-i-asked-do-i-ask-again-or-completely-revise-the-question)  to revise the question.  After a few days with no objection to the comment, I assumed that I should follow it.  If you disagree, maybe posting a comment or answer to the Meta question would be useful for others in the future.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you're saying is wrong with the first equation" See previous comment, what is unclear in it?

Comment: @Did, well, I'm not sure what you mean by "depends on".  Both sides include all of the same variables, and in both cases it's $x_n$ that's conditioned on.  RHS is just an application of the definition of conditional expectation for a discrete distribution.  I did not find the meaning of the dot obvious, initially, but now I understand that in this equation the dot indicates that the expectation on the left is over $x_{n+1}$.  That is why the conditional probability on the right is $p(x_{n+1}|x_n)$.  (I don't know whether any of this is relevant to your point.)

Comment: "Both sides include all of the same variables" No. Please reread either your question or my comment.

Comment: @Did I am almost not sure we are looking at the same equation.  Is there a MathJax formatting bug in the site?  If it's not that, then if you are unwilling to be more specific in order to illuminate me, that's OK.  I am looking, but I'm not sure this discussion is useful for either of us.  (You may consider me a poor student and either help me learn or kick me out of the class as uneducable.)

Comment: Not my approach, sorry. But if you refuse to read my comment, it is true that I am wondering how I could help you any further. No big deal.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  Thanks for trying.  (For the record, I have read your comment many times now.)

Comment: @Did: $x_{1:n}$ is in the paper introduced as a shorthand for $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Does that solve your issue?

Comment: This is not "my" issue and the shorthand is well-known.

Answer (score 0):

I now see what is missing, and per @equaeghe's suggestion in a comment, I'll answer my own question.  (Apologies to those who don't like self-answered questions.  I do think this may be useful to others reading the article that was the subject of the question.)

The middle part of equation (6),

$$E(E(f(x_{1:N-2},\cdot,\cdot)|x_{1:N-2}, \cdot)\,|\,x_{1:N-2})$$

and the final expression derived in the question,

$$E[E(f(x_{1:N-2},x_{N-1},x_N)|x_{N-1})|x_{N-2}]$$

are equal because we're assuming the sequence has the Markov property.  That is, conditioning on $x_{1:N-2}$ is the same as conditioning on $x_{N-2}$, and conditioning on $(x_{1:N-2}, \cdot) = x_{1:N-1}$ is the same as conditioning on $x_{N-1}$.  This kind of substitution was illustrated in equation (5) in the original article.